# Footer flickers when moving to different pages

Tags: html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have the following markup to display a fixed footer in the main layout:

```
<nav class="main-footer navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light" style="height: 40px;">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
            <a href="" class="nav-link"><strong>MySite</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About" class="nav-link">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="PrivacyPolicy" class="nav-link">Privacy Policy</a>
        </li>   
        <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Terms" class="nav-link">Terms</a>
        </li>
    </ul>     
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            Your IP: @(ipAddress)  
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

With this markup, the footer keeps flickering when moving between pages.

I was previously using the `footer` tag which was working great but I changed to the above code to have the `nav` items like in the header.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Whether the `Footer` is fixed or not when it is flickering? I checked your code in my application, it seems that there has a vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the issue relates the `nav`'s  height attribute. If you want to set the height for the Footer, try to set the `line-height` attribute in the `footer` element. Code as below:

```
@{
    var ipAddress = "";
    if (ViewBag.ipAddress != null)
    {
        ipAddress = ViewBag.ipAddress;
    }
    else
    {
        ipAddress = "Null";
    }
}
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted" style="line-height:40px !important;" > 
        <nav class="main-footer navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light" >
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link"><strong>MySite</strong></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="PrivacyPolicy" class="nav-link">Privacy Policy</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Terms" class="nav-link">Terms</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    Your IP: @(ipAddress)
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav> 
</footer>
```

Then, the result like this:

[image]

Update:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">WebApplication1</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    @{
        var ipAddress = "";
        if (ViewBag.ipAddress != null)
        {
            ipAddress = ViewBag.ipAddress;
        }
        else
        {
            ipAddress = "Null";
        }
    }
    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted" style="line-height:40px !important;" > 
            <nav class="main-footer navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light" >
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link"><strong>MySite</strong></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About" class="nav-link">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="PrivacyPolicy" class="nav-link">Privacy Policy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Terms" class="nav-link">Terms</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        Your IP: @(ipAddress)
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav> 
    </footer>
    @*<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
            <div class="container">
                &copy; 2021 - WebApplication1 - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
            </div>
        </footer>*@
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is still there because there is a scrollbar even though the page content is small.

Comment: Hi @Ivan-MarkDebono, if that is the case, the issue might relate other CSS style (as we can see that in my sample, there doesn't have the scrollbar), I will post the whole Layout page source, you could refer to it. Besides, you could also create a similar sample to reproduce the problem.